# loops and how to pull the name of companies starting with S

Tags: javascript, loops

Trying to finish the `if` statement to pull the name of companies with letter S.

```
var sCompanies = [];

for (var i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++){
  console.log (sCompanies[i]);
}
 if 

var sLength = sCompanies.length;

console.log(sCompanies);
console.log(sLength);
```

I'm trying to solve how to pull the companies with the letter S. I know I will need to use an if statement but confusing myself how to write in properly.

Comment: so something `if(tickers[i].includes("s"))` in your `for` loop might work

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` with a check using `startsWith`

```
 sCompanies = tickers.filter(co => co.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith('s'));
```

Or can use regex

```
sCompanies = tickers.filter(co => /^s/i.test(co));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var tickers = ["s1", "a1", "s2"]

var sCompanies = [];

for (var i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++){

    if ( tickers[i].length > 0 && tickers[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase() === "s"){
        sCompanies.push(tickers[i]);
    }
}
var sLength = sCompanies.length;

console.log(sCompanies);

console.log(sLength);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
const sCompanies = tickers.filter(co => /s/i.test(co[0]))
```

Code example:

```js
const tickers = [
  'Saas',
  'Google'
]
const sCompanies = tickers.filter(co => /s/i.test(co[0]))

console.log(sCompanies)
```